# cakephp displayfield confuse?

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm creating a small application in cakephp 2.0

i have tree model  DescCriter belongs Aspects , Aspects belongs Activits  and Activits belong Plans

I change in all model public $displayField = 'descripcion';

But went i want display something diferent to id .. in my view i cant..

I dont how fix... the only thing i can see are id

add model code

```
class DescCriter extends AppModel {
   public $displayField = 'Criterio'; 
    public $validate = array(
        'aspects_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Aspects' => array(
            'className' => 'Aspects',
            'foreignKey' => 'aspects_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );


class Aspect extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'descripcion';
    public $validate = array(
        'activits_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Activits' => array(
            'className' => 'Activits',
            'foreignKey' => 'activits_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

class Activit extends AppModel {

   public $displayField = 'descripcion'; 
    public $validate = array(
        'plans_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Plans' => array(
            'className' => 'Plans',
            'foreignKey' => 'plans_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

// controler aspects

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Activit->create();
            if ($this->Activit->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The activit has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The activit could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $plans = $this->Activit->Plans->find('list');

        $this->set(compact('plans'));
    }
```

// controler Activitis

```
 public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Aspect->create();
                if ($this->Aspect->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The aspect has been saved'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The aspect could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
            $activits = $this->Aspect->Activits->find('list');
            $this->set(compact('activits'));
        }
```

//view  aspect add

```
<div class="aspects form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Aspect'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Aspect'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('descripcion');
        echo $this->Form->input('activits_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Aspects'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Activits'), array('controller' => 'activits', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Activits'), array('controller' => 'activits', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

//View activities add

```
<div class="activits form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Activit'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Activit'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('descripcion');
        echo $this->Form->input('plans_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Activits'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Plans'), array('controller' => 'plans', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Plans'), array('controller' => 'plans', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) explain specific problem 2) you mention "View", but show literally no View code  3) you don't even have your `finds()`.  So translating this question, it sounds like you're asking "Please write me some code".

Comment: i put code.. for view (add) and controller...

Comment: You can set the value of the input - see the CakePHP book for details (IF that's what you're asking).